# QMetaObject::invokeMethod returns true but doesn't execute the solt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qmetaobject

I'm trying to run a public slot in another thread using `invokeMethod`:

```
QMetaObject::invokeMethod(m_manager, "onEventRequest", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(int, 0));
```

Now, `invokeMethod` returns true and no error message are reported, but the slot `onEventRequest` is never called. I added a breakpoint in `onEventRequest` which is never triggered.

`m_manager` is created in the main thread, this class inherits `QObject` and uses the `Q_OBJECT` macro `invokeMethod` is executed in another thread created by `QThread::run()`.

I would appreciate any help on this, or on how to check why the method is not being called.

Comment: Are you sure the target thread has an event loop running? Check `m_manager->thread()->isRunning()`

Comment: *another thread created by QThread::run()* - the [run](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html#run) function does not create a QThread. I suggest you provide more code, in the form of an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As it stands, the question lacks detail required for others to help you and answers are only likely to be guesses as to what the problem is.